# How To Get Food Dye Off My Hands?

Tags: food, color

I'm so mad at myself! I had been good about keeping my hands clean of dye until this morning. I was in a rush to load the dishwasher and wasn't thinking. Now I have red dye all over my hands. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I use bleach and water and soak them for a few minutes. If they are really stained with red it may take straight bleach. After that I use liquid soap or even dawn detergent. And yes, don't forget to use lotion afterwards. Of course it would have had to be red. It is rather difficult to remove food dye from the skin. It can leave visible stains on your hands, especially if you do not use gloves. Researched google and see some simple source of [effective methods to clean food coloring](https://improveeats.com/how-to-get-food-coloring-off-skin/) from your skin should be help you. N.B: Before you begin, rub shortening on your hands. This is especially helpful if kneading color into fondant.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Joyce Goodwin?

Answer (score 2):

For small areas such as an ink stain, I use a pumice stone to *gently* rub the dye off.

[image]

You might need to use this if other answers do not work. Do not scrub hard, because it abrades the skin. It might take some time to gently work your way around the hands.

Answer (score 0):

printing press operators get their hands extremely inky all the time. There is a scrubbing cream specifically designed to take colorants off human skin which can be bought from a place that sells commercial printing supplies. I'm sorry but I cannot remember the brand name.